# How to target specific list item in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML & JQUERY:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $target = $('number4');
   $target.fadeOut('fast');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Remember!
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li class='hi'>Start with the function keyword</li>
        <li>Inputs go between ()</li>
        <li>Actions go between {}</li>
        <li class='number4'>jQuery is for chumps!</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Inputs are separated by commas.</li>
    <li>Inputs can include other functions!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wanted the four element in my ordered list to fadeout when the document is ready, but it is not working. I tried identifying the fourth ordered list element with class='number4' and then targeting that identifier in the jQuery, but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is many ways to target the item ... but your code must work the mistake `$('number4')` must be `$('.number4')`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? "Not working" could either mean "Thowing exceptions" or "Doing nothing".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably this works

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.number4').fadeOut('fast');
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error? Maybe you need to declare `$target` as `var $target`?

Comment: Thank you! This actually solved my error. I figured out when targeting specific classes in jQuery, you have put a period ('.') before the name of the class.

Comment: yes that is right, I updated it too :)

Answer (score 1):

This works you have to map the parent child relationships

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $target = $("div>ul>li>ol>li:nth-child(4)");
    // or var $target= $("div>ul>li>ol>li:last-child");
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
 });
```

You don't need to set an id with the :nth-child selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/o7sxoton/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $target = $('.number4');
   $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Note: You made the syntax error on selector $('.number4');

For select last list, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $target = $('.numbered-list li:last'); // For avoid direct tag selector, use class or id
   $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/nohena/edit?html,js,console,output